# use add_action in a shortcode (gravity form - Wordpress)

Tags: functions, shortcode, actions

I have a shortcode.
With this one, i get the ID (number) of a formular $num_formular.
Then, with this one, i had to send all the data in the database.

When I run the following code, it works:

```
function ss_get_appbenutzer($atts, $content = null){
//global $num_formular;
/* Récupération du numéro du formulaire*/   
$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'num_formular' => 'NUM_formular'
    ), $atts);
$num_formular = $atts['num_formular']; 
echo 'NUM Formulaire DANS SHORTCODE ='.$num_formular;
}
add_shortcode( 'app-benutzer' , 'ss_get_appbenutzer' );
add_action('gform_after_submission_192', 'msk_gform_process_user_registration_192', 10, 2);

function msk_gform_process_user_registration_192 ($entry, $form) {
echo 'PASSAGE DANS FONCTION msk_gform_process_user_registration_MB --> ok ';
}};
```

and it prints :

NUM Formulaire DANS SHORTCODE =192
PASSAGE DANS FNCTION msk_gform_process_user_registration_MB --> ok

So it works and the data are in the database.

BUT, i get the number of the formular because it will be various number of formular.

So, i need to have $num_formular as a variable.
Then I must use call add_action like this :

```
function ss_get_appbenutzer($atts, $content = null){
//global $num_formular;
/* Récupération du numéro du formulaire*/   
$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'num_formular' => 'NUM_formular'
    ), $atts);
$num_formular = $atts['num_formular']; 
echo 'NUM Formulaire DANS SHORTCODE ='.$num_formular;
}
add_shortcode( 'app-benutzer' , 'ss_get_appbenutzer' );

$gform = "'gform_after_submission_".$num_formular."'";
add_action($gform, 'msk_gform_process_user_registration_MB', 10, 2);

function msk_gform_process_user_registration_MB ($entry, $form) {
echo 'PASSAGE DANS FONCTION msk_gform_process_user_registration_MB --> ok ';
}};
```

But the $num_formular is unknown outside the funtion ss_get_appbenutzer.
I tried to use global, but i didn't find something working.
And i realized that global is not really a good solution.

Then, i tried to include add_action inside the ss_get_appbenutzer function, like this (i took the code which was working)

```
function ss_get_appbenutzer($atts, $content = null){
//global $num_formular;
/* Récupération du numéro du formulaire*/   
$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'num_formular' => 'NUM_formular'
    ), $atts);
$num_formular = $atts['num_formular']; 
echo 'NUM Formulaire DANS SHORTCODE ='.$num_formular;
add_action('gform_after_submission_192', 'msk_gform_process_user_registration_192', 10, 2);
}

add_shortcode( 'app-benutzer' , 'ss_get_appbenutzer' );

function msk_gform_process_user_registration_192 ($entry, $form) {
echo 'PASSAGE DANS FONCTION msk_gform_process_user_registration_MB --> ok ';
}};
```

but it prints only 
NUM Formulaire DANS SHORTCODE =192

That means that the add_action, placed here in the ss_get_appbenutzer function, doesn't work (or is not called).

COuld you please give me some hint to make this add_action working?

I am really really stuckked and i tried so many things that i don't know where to search now.

Many thanks for your help

Timama

Comment: The reason it's not working is because `gform_after_submission_192 ` has presumably already run by the time the shortcode is printed. Honestly, what you're trying to do doesn't make a lot of sense. Why are you using a shortcode for this> It looks like you want to do something after a Gravity Form is submitted, but why would you use a shortcode to do that? Can you explain in more detail what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: many thanks for your comment. Okay, i didn't  give a good explanation.
The simple example (for only one form) :
I have a page (built with wordpress).
In this page, there is a registration form.
I use shortcode in  wordpress, for this page, to have the registration form in this page. So I need the shortcode (it is the way to put the form in a page for gravity form).

Comment: Then, i used the shortcode to get the number of this registration form.
With this one, I can use add_action with the good numer of registration form and save the datas in the databank.

The thing is that I have various number of registration form.

That's  why i am trying to have this "automatic" and not  create code each time I have a new form.

Comment: Gravity Forms has a hook, [`gform_after_submission`](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_after_submission/), that runs for every form. Can't you just use that? And what is the `app-benutzer` shortcode for? You've described what the Gravity Forms shortcode is for, but not this one. I don't know why you need this shortcode at all, when you can just use `add_action()` in your functions file outside of a shortcode.

Comment: thanks for this comment.
app-benutzer is the tag (the name) of the shortcode which uses the function ss_get_appbenutzer.
So, the shortcode app-benutzer is the one I explained (there is only one shortcode).

I use gform_after_submission (as you can see in my code below).
I want it to run for specific form, not for all.
can I just use add_action('gform_after_submission', 'msk_gform_process_user_registration', 10, 2); ? how does it connect the add_action with the form ?

Comment: Look, the problem is that a shortcode is a _terrible_ way to handle form processing. Not least because in Gravity Forms it's impossible, because the form has already been processed. If you have something you want to do in the background when a Gravity Form is submitted then you should create a Feed add-on: https://docs.gravityforms.com/gffeedaddon/#introduction The only other option is to hard-code which form IDs you want to process into your code.

Comment: oh that looks bad to use shortcode for form processing?
I thought it was the way to do it becuse it is explained in the gravity documentation.
https://docs.gravityforms.com/shortcodes/

But , if you say so. I check the Feed add-on.... (i have a quick look, i need more time to understand....) but i don't really want to create an add-on.
I have used the hint in the following page ("Récupérer les données d’un formulaire après soumission d’un Gravity Forms")
https://mosaika.fr/astuces-developpement-gravity-forms-wordpress/

Comment: What? Nothing in that gravity forms document has _anything_ to do with processing a form with a second shortcode. The second link doesn't say anything about using a shortcode either. Their `add_action()` is not inside a shortcode.

Comment: oh your are completely right..... When i call the gravity form, i do that
[gravityform id=192 title=false]
[app-benutzer NUM_formular=192]  
I understand what you mean now... i was focused on something else and forgot this point...

So, the base (using this second shortcode), is not a good idea to get the number of the form. (many thanks for insisting, i was blind ). Then how can i do? because i need to get it.
Can I get it in [gravityform id=192 title=false] ? and give it an specific name ? in order to use it? ..... i am searching

Comment: I think I must explain the base of this question.

I have a form A with the title AAA.
I have a page, with this form inside.

I duplicate the form A into the form B, and change the title with BBB.
I duplicate the form A into the form C, and change the title with CCC.
And create the page to insert the new form.

Etc.

Then, I have for example 100 pages and 100 forms which only have their titles different.

Comment: I would like that once these forms are completed, the datas of the forms go into the database.
As a page (with a form inside) can be create (the form duplicate) at any time by a person who doesn’t know coding, how can I make this process automatic?

This is the big issue…. That’s why I had a shortcode to get the number of the form….

so i think I have to rethink the whole problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussing in the comments, I can surmise that this is your situation:

1. You have functionality for processing a user registration in some way when a form is submitted.
2. You need a way in the CMS to specify *which* forms this processing needs to happen for.

What it looks like you're attempting to do is add a shortcode to the page with a matching form ID so that when the form is submitted the processing occurs for that form.

There are several problems with this:

1. Shortcodes are intended for displaying dynamic contnet inside a post or page. They are not intended for back-end events like form processing.
2. When a Gravity Form is submitted, it is processed before the page content is reloaded. This means that it's too late to attempt to hook into the form submission hook, because it has already run and finished.

The 'proper' way to develop this would be to develop a "feed", which is how Gravity Forms supports developers providing a way to add their functionality to specific forms via the UI. The documentation for creating custom feed types is available [here](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gffeedaddon/#introduction). In your case you would put your registration processing into the `process_feed` method of your custom feed.

However, as you've suggested, it is quite a lot of work to create an add-on feed. So, I'm going to suggest a workaround:

1. Add a hidden field to the forms that you wish to process.
2. Hook into `gform_after_submission` for all forms and check for this hidden field. If the hidden field is present, process the registration.

So, for the first step, add a [Hidden field](https://docs.gravityforms.com/hidden/#common-settings) to the forms that you need to be processed. Give it a label that makes sense for you. I'll assume "App Benutzer", just based on the shortcode name.

Now, this is what your code will be:

```
function msk_gform_process_user_registration_MB( $entry, $form ) {
    $fields = $form['fields'];

    // Check every field in the form.
    foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
        // If our hidden field has been added to this form, process the user registration.
        if ( $field->label = 'App Benutzer' ) {
            // Process user registration here.
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'msk_gform_process_user_registration_MB', 10, 2 );
```

So this solves the problem of allowing non-technical users a way to tell Gravity Forms which forms the user registration should be processed for: They just need to add a Hidden field with the label "App Benutzer".

Comment: oh that is a good idea ! the hidden field ! Many thanks Jacob !
I m tring this right now and tell if it works... i'l be back

Comment: Keep in mind that `// Process user registration here.` won't be occurring in the page content, so any messages you try to print might not appear. I suggesting logging messages to the error log with `error_log( 'message here' )` if you want to see if it's working.

Comment: Jacob, it works !
So many thanks ! I really didn't think about this hidden filed.. and it is so simple !
Don't you think it can slow down the website speed if there are too many forms ?
as here, every forms are tested ....

Comment: I can't imagine any performance problems. Whenever a form is submitted the code will need to check every field looking for the hidden field, but this should be pretty quick, since there's no database calls involved. If you have forms with _lots_ of fields, then it might take slightly longer for them to submit, but the rest of the site would be unaffected.

Comment: thanks for this answer. So, I put the hidden field on the top.
How can I thank you ! you really helped me !
Thank you for insiting at the begining, that made me look somewhere else and Then your idea to take the problem in another way is perfect !
SO many thanks !